# How can I create duplicate rows for each row in a table that does not contain a specific value?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-insert

Keep in mind, this IS for homework. I've been stuck on this problem for at least a week now.

I need to add a row to the table `Vendors` for each vendor (each has a `VendorID`, and `VendorName`) that does not have a `VendorState` value of `CA`.

I'm not quite grasping how to exclude rows with a specific value, but I suspect a sub-query is involved.

Any help is much appreciated.

edit--
here is the question word for word

> Write an INSERT statement that adds a row to the VendorCopy table for
>   each non-California vendor in the Vendors table. (This will result in
>   duplicate vendors in the VendorCopy table.)

Comment: add your table design and more details and how you tried..

Comment: Please, add table structure first.

Comment: Details of the assignment and table structure provided will help a lot solve your problem.

Comment: @RajatJaiswal || table structure is just the names of the columns and their data types... right?

Comment: @Bobalobdob feel free to read up on [what to do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use **cursor** for retrieve each row data in select query.

If I have understood correctly your question you can use this script for insert new row for specific condition:

```
insert into Vendors
SELECT 'new val' col1,'new val' col2, VendorState FROM Vendors
where VendorState <> 'ca'
```

------------Edit---------------------

if you want to create new table (copy of vendor) you can use this script:

```
SELECT * into Vendors_Copy FROM Vendors
WHERE VendorState <> 'ca'
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need this query:

```
INSERT INTO table_vendors (VendorName, VendorState)
SELECT VendorName, VendorState FROM table_vendors WHERE VendorState != 'CA'
```

Keep in mind that if VendorId is a primary key or no duplicate index, you need this field to auto increment. Also, You need to specify all fields except VendorId because you can't duplicate the ID.

Comment: The original table is called [Vendors] and the table to insert to is called [VendorCopy]. It is not clear (yet) if table [VendorCopy] already exists or not... If the target table exists, you can use a INSERT...SELECT query, but if the target table does not exist, you can use a SELECT...INTO query.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may be

```
Insert into some_Other (col1, col2 ...)
SELECT v.VendorName, o.State 
FROM table_vendors v
CROSS APPLY table_state o
where v.vendor_id = o.vendorid and v.vendor_state != 'CA'
```